# Add custom handler to log root level with logging.basicConfig()

Tags: python, logging, handler

I am trying to build a custom log handler which sends log messages over http. However, I do not want to add the handler with `addHandler()` method. I want the custom handler to be configured directly at log root level with `logging.basicConfig()` in particular to ensure all log messages triggered from different modules with **different loggers** are sent over http. How can I achieve this?

Here is my current code

```py
"""Entrypoint to execute python scripts."""
import argparse
import logging
import sys
import utils
from batch import Batch
from data_source import DataSource


# Load default logging configuration
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# Define custom log handler
class CustomLogHandler(logging.Handler):
    """Custom logs handler to send log messages to GraphQL API."""

    def __init__(self, authorization: str, batch_id: int):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        self.authorization = authorization
        self.batch_id = str(batch_id)

    def emit(self, log_record):
        file_name = log_record.name
        log_level = log_record.levelname
        log_message = self.format(log_record)

        # Do stuff here...
        utils.execute_graphql_request(self.authorization, mutation)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Entry point to execute data quality scripts.')
    parser.add_argument('authorization', type=str, help='Authentication token of the user')
    parser.add_argument('method', type=str, help='Method to be executed: execute_batch, test_data_source')
    parser.add_argument('id', type=int, help='Id of the object on which to execute the method.')
    arguments = parser.parse_args()

    authorization = arguments.authorization
    method = arguments.method

    if method == 'execute_batch':
        batch_id = arguments.id

        # Overwrite log root basic config to send logs to GraphQL API when executing a batch
        logging.basicConfig(
            level=logging.INFO,
            format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
            handlers=[logging.StreamHandler(), CustomLogHandler(authorization, batch_id)])

        batch = Batch()
        batch.execute(authorization, batch_id)

    elif [...]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have two ways of adding a handler to the root logger,
either add it to the `basicConfig`:

```
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.INFO,
        format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
        handlers=[
            logging.StreamHandler(),
            CustomLogHandler()
        ]
    )
```

or after your basic config is done you can add it to the root logger (to ensure propagation) like this:

```
root_log = logging.getLogger()
root_log.addHandler(CustomLogHandler())
```

then whenever you do a

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.info("message")
```

The "message" log should be sent through your root logger.